# MemoryStream data corruption issue

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, stream, basichttpbinding

I have created a simple REST based WCF service which runs on `BasicHttpBinding`. In one of my webmethod, I am  returning a Stream which points to a JSON response.

The Method looks like :

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ApplicationFault))]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetActiveCalls/{nurseid}")]
Stream GetActiveCalls(string nurseid);
```

From the body of the `GetActiveCalls`, I am creating an object of `MemoryStream` and returning the same as response. The code looks like

```
// Serialize the results as JSON
string jsonResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(baseResponses);

// ContentType json
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonResult);
//Parse to memorystream
var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
ms.SetLength(bytes.LongLength);
return ms;
```

When trying this from client, I get result like

```
{"LastEvents":[{"FormatValues":"Klic 2 3 4","Icon":null,"Color":"Red","Acknowledged":false,"EventID":28566}],"Message":"","Status":true}
```

But sometimes after invoking the same method for multiple times, I start getting the response as :

```
{"LastEvents":[{"FormatValues":"Klic 2 3 4","Icon":null,"Color":"Red","Acknowledged":false,"EventID":28566}],"Message":"","Statu{"LastEv
```

You can see after `"Statu` on the JSON response, the stream gets reset and starts getting data from the beginning.

It looks strange to me.

*From server side, when I put breakpoint, it seems the `MemoryStream` has correct response.

Comment: Curious, is there a reason you're manually serializing this?  If all you're doing is passing back a `MemoryStream`, then you aren't saving much, as you have to materialize the full result set before you send it off.  If you're sending back JSON, you generally don't need it.

Comment: Hmm. you mean I dont need to Serilize the object, and rather write the object directly ?

Comment: Yes, why not just make the return value your object and let WCF handle the serialization over the wire?

Comment: I have just changed and now returning the object. I think now I have to define the object as DataContract? I have added the Datacontract attribute to the class which is getting returned and it seems now the service returns 504 result.

Answer (score 3):

Putting aside the question of using a memory stream or not, I encountered a similar issue just recently, where the memory stream response appeared corrupted, seemingly randomly. The solution to this problem was to remove the tracing sections from web.config, which I had turned on in dev mode. This may or may not be your issue, but it might be worth having a look at. Seems as though this problem is still present in .NET 4.5 as well.

Comment: I have fixed the problem already. but still thanks for contributing to the wiki. :)

Comment: @aldous-zodiac - brilliant! I was having the same issue; oddly, with the same data it always corrupted at the same point and in the same number of requests (it would be fine for the first eight requests from the server, on the ninth request it would corrupt). Once I followed your advice and disabled tracing, I could throw it through as many requests as I wanted without any corruption.